# Setting a rails active record default_scope order that depends on an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, associations

I have two models, Post and Comment.  Each post has many comments.  I would like to order my posts by which post has the most recent comment.

I am attempting to set a default_scope on my Post model as follows:

```
default_scope :order => 'posts.comments.last.updated_at DESC'
```

. . but I get a PGError when I attempt that.  What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
default_scope.joins(:comments).find(:all, :order => 'comments.updated_at DESC', :group => 'id')
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
default_scope :joins => :comments, :order => 'comments.updated_at DESC', :group => 'id'
```

Comment: That works but results in duplicates.  'comments.last.updated_at DESC' doesn't work either.  Is there a way to call last or to enforce uniqueness?

Comment: With ":group => 'id'", I get 'PGError: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous'  In case it's important, when I'm calling posts, it's from another model associated with posts: 'deal.posts'